# Could not open table in Visual Basic 6.0, generated in PowerDesigner 6 AppModeler

Tags: ms-access, vb6, basic, powerdesigner

I'm trying to make an app using Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0.

My problem is that VB cannot open tables, outputing a message "Could not open table 'Table'!" though Visual Data Manager opens it fine.

What could be the problem? Could it be something with CRYSTL32.OCX and DBGRID32.OCX file that also cannot load? Or there's something that should be corrected while an app in AppModeler is generated?

P.S. Tables generated in MS Access using *.vbp script file are filling in OK.

Comment: If it's VB6, it should not be tagged vb.net

Comment: Yes, it's VB6. Where can I untag it?

Comment: Edit the question by clicking the `Edit` link underneath the question text. At the bottom of the edit window is a section headed **Tags**. There you can click on the "X" next to `vb.net` to remove that tag and you can also type "vb6" to add that tag.

Comment: If you have two OCXs that can't load, would probably be worth fixing those, and see if that does indeed fix the other issue. Might be a dll common to the 3 is missing or such

Comment: So, today I tried to load my project on another computer, which has Windows XP as a root OS (my XP is on Virtual Machine).

The result is - absolutely everything loaded fine, no errors at all. Except for the tables while running Visual Basic app - it still says "Couldn't open table!".

So the reason is not those *.OCX files, but smth different. So far, no more ideas, what could be the problem.

Comment: If your references (such as the 2 OCX files mentioned) are properly registered, the OS version likely has nothing to do with it.